# console.log()/dir() in javascript when not natively supported by browser

Tags: javascript, css

I have to print JavaScript objects for a debugger project, and it must run on browsers without console (IE with no devtools, older FF without firebug, mobile browsers not connected to a remote debugger, etc)

I started to write a stand alone version of firebug's console dir() and its CSS and realized i am surely not the first one to need that.

But my search foo failed. What is the term i should be searching for?

All i could find so far is people repeating the same mistakes i was about to (i.e. writting a one off clone of console.dir just for their immediate need, instead of using/starting a general purposed solution)

http://codetheory.in/mongodb-pretty-print-result-objects-in-mongo-interactive-shell/

https://github.com/hij1nx/cdir (this one is for the console, so i can understand going the independent implementation route)

Comment: what would console.log do if you don't have a console in the browser?

Comment: You can create a console proxy in the document and display the messages there.  At the very least, you can override the method and prevent it from throwing errors and breaking your scripts.

Comment: @Lucho trhow an error when trying to access property log of null? but this is besides the point, i need to show the information. not work around browsers not having console.log(). I want to see the object dump on those browser too!